# How to raise a toast in AsyncTask, I am prompted to used the Looper

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast, looper

I have tasks completed by AsyncTask in background. At some point I need to issue a Toast that something is completed.

I've tried and I failed because 
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

onPostExecute - executes on UI thread
or 
 `publishProgress()`; in your doinbackground and

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I have to issue the Toast in the middle of the process, not in the end. What are my options?

Comment: onProgressUpdate. It also runs on UI thread and Toast should be fine

Comment: -1 downvoted because every other answer to this question is better than this one!

Comment: oops, undownvoted because i did not notice the `onProgressUpdate` and only noticed the `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 27):

you can Toast inside doInBackground

add this code where you want to Toast appear

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

    Toast.makeText(<your class name>.this, "Cool Ha?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method to manipulate your UI from background threads.

Comment: works for me. Just needed to call getActivivty().runOnUiThread(...)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use Toast
You should use this method : onProgressUpdate()

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Void...Params) {
   int check_point = 1;
   publishProgress(check_point);
   return check_point;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer integers) {
  if(integers == 1) {
    Toast.makeText(classname.this, "Text", 0).show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the Toast from the background thread you'll have to call runOnUiThread from doInBackground.  I don't believe there's another way.

Edit: I take that back.  I think you can implement onProgressUpdate, which runs on the UI thread, to show the Toast and make calls to publishProgress from doInBackground.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the Toast in doInBackground, you can use it in the OnPostExecute method of AsyncTask.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {    
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   pDialog.dismiss();//dismiss the progress dialouge
}
```