# Async Worker Crashes App

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have written the following code within the main class for an async worker

```
private class Renderer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "works... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }





         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

         }
     }
```

But calling this crashes the app

```
public void render(View v)
    {
        new Renderer().execute();
    }
```

Can some one tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a `Toast` in `doInBackground`, you will get `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.

If it's just for testing at this stage (which your code seems to imply), consider instead just writing some log output for now.

Alternatively put your `Toast` either `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute`

More info: [How to raise a toast in AsyncTask, I am prompted to used the Looper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837676/how-to-raise-a-toast-in-asynctask-i-am-prompted-to-used-the-looper)

Comment: does not work even after putting the toast in Onpostexecute.App does not crash but nothing happens

Comment: Your `AsyncTask` is wrong. Put `@Override` before all the methods and follow what eclipse tells you to do. `onPostExecute()` is not being called at all as the method signature should be `protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {` according to your `AsyncTask` declaration. **SHORT ANSWER**: Change onPostExecute to `(Void result)` NOT `(Long result)` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You are showing toast in `doInbackground` which is not possible. Do it in `onPostExecute`

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "works... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

`doInbackground` is invoked on the background thread. You should update ui on the ui thread. You can alos display toast in  `onProgressUpdate`.

More info at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Check the topic under the section **The 4 steps**.

Comment: okay,but does not work even after putting the toast in Onpostexecute.App does not crash but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can't access UI thread from background thread.

Answer (score 0):

An `AsyncTask` is a helper around `Threads` and `Handlers`. It helps you to perform a background task and update the UI regularly.

Thus, the methods of `AsyncTask` run on different `Threads`:
`doInBackground` runs in a background Thread
`onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` run on the UI `Thread`.

Now, you can only modify the UI in the UI `Thread` (=main `Thread`). This is why your code leads to a crash. Simply moving your `Toast` into `onPostExecute` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() { 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "works... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
                });`
```

Try to do all ui work on main thread.